# After xfs repair how can you recover file names?

Tags: linux, xfs

All well pretty much all the files are in lost and found, I had a corrupt drive and before I quite knew what I was doing I used xfs repair most of the files have names but a lot have numbers

Can I rebuild the inode numbers or have more of a file system instead of a large list of numbered files?

Comment: Probably not. If that kind of information was still intact, xfs_repair would have tried to recover it

Comment: @MarcusMüller so there’s no internal log files for that ?

Comment: sure, that's what gets checked every mount. If that information was in the log, then it wouldn't have needed repairing.

Comment: Hmm maybe it was a dual disk setup and the other disk is gone I thought this was the root but if it’s spread across 2 disks I suppose the main log huge parts of it could be gone ahh well